# How to fix complicated HTML encoding for URL in python script?

Tags: python, html, url, python-2.7, url-encoding

I have a nightmare situation on my hands (or maybe it is easy, I don't know)...So I have a small function that runs in a rather large python script...I have everything worked out in the larger script, and at the end the script will call our web map services and show the parcels in question...We have 20K parcels, and ONLY 10 of them have a '%' in the Deedholder name. So this works over 99% of the time, but there is always that 1% (or way less in this case)

The problem is, in the rare situation where there is a percent sign in the deedholder name, when I supply a url it cannot find the query.  So I have tested a ton of names, and it only will not work when there is a percent sign in the name.

So the prefix will look like this:

'https://cedar.integritygis.com/default.aspx?ql=Parcel&qf=REALDATA_DEEDHOLDER&qv='

and the name is added to the end, which looks like this:

'COOPER MICHAEL A & DEBRA K'

My code can easily replace the spaces with '%20' and the & with '%26'...etc.  But what do I do when THIS is the deedholder name:

'SIEBELS LAWRENCE J (75%) & LOUISE F TRUST (25%)'

I cannot successfully get this query to work.  Here is my test code with just the function in question:

```
import webbrowser, time

def FixURL(string):

##    string = string.replace('%','~')
    print string
    fix_dict = {' ':'%20','!':'%21','"':'%22','#':'%23','$':'%24',
                '&':'%26',"'":'%27','(':'%28',')':'%29',
                '*':'%2A','+':'%2b','.':'%2E','/':'%2F',':':'%3A',
                ';':'%3B','?':'%3F','@':'%40','{':'%7B','{':'%7D'}

    for k,v in fix_dict.iteritems():
        if k in string:
            string = string.replace(k,v)
##    return string.replace('~','%25')
    return string

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # testing
    easy = FixURL('COOPER MICHAEL A & DEBRA K')
    prefix = 'https://cedar.integritygis.com/default.aspx?ql=Parcel&qf=REALDATA_DEEDHOLDER&qv='
    url = '{}{}'.format(prefix,easy)
    print easy
    webbrowser.open(url)
    time.sleep(15)  # give it time to work

    hard = FixURL('SIEBELS LAWRENCE J (75%) & LOUISE F TRUST (25%)')
    print hard
    url = '{}{}'.format(prefix,hard)
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

I cannot figure out how to 'trick' it...You can see my unsucessful attempts are commented out.  Does anyone have a fix?  One thing I am thinking of doing is removing the space from the dictionary and using '%20'.join(string.split()) and testing each item in the list for replacement values for the url...Does have any ideas?  It seems I have been squeezed by Python yet again.  Thanks.

EDIT:

I have since scratched the entire function and am just urllib.quote(). this as a test:

```
import webbrowser, urllib, time

prefix = 'https://cedar.integritygis.com/default.aspx?ql=Parcel&qf=REALDATA_DEEDHOLDER&qv='
easy = urllib.quote('COOPER MICHAEL A & DEBRA K')
url = '{}{}'.format(prefix,easy)
print easy
webbrowser.open(url)
time.sleep(15)  # give it time to work

hard = urllib.quote('SIEBELS LAWRENCE J (75%) & LOUISE F TRUST (25%)')
print hard
url = '{}{}'.format(prefix,hard)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

This is suppposed to zoom to the parcels owned by the name supplied...The first one works, the second does not because of the % in the parenthesis (I think).  I get the 'ol query returned no results error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's standard `urllib` to do this.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#utility-functions

Look at the utility functions. `urllib.quote` will probably do the job.

Comment: Wow, I do not know why I did not look to use that in the first place...I guess I can scratch the entire function...However, it did not work for the problem one:

Comment: This did not work:

 hard = urllib.quote('SIEBELS LAWRENCE J (75%) & LOUISE F TRUST (25%)')

Comment: Thanks again...but no luck. It is basically giving me the same result my function did...I have now replaced the FixURL() with urllib.quote() and still no dice.  Still having problems encoding that '%' sign.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the output you want, and what output did urllib.quote give?

Comment: See the edit I just made to the question...I am using urllib.quote() instead of the function and the second name will still not work.  If you test my second piece of code with urllib, you will see that the url does not return any results. The first one does (COOPER) The name is correct, it was copied straight from the database.  I am not sure how urllib.quote() handles any '%' characters, but it does not seem to work in this case.  Thanks.

Comment: SIEBELS%20LAWRENCE%20J%20%2875%25%29%20%26%20LOUISE%20F%20TRUST%20%2825%25%29   

is the output

Comment: Do you know for sure that you have the right deedholder name? You could also try escaping the % first (i.e. replace '75%' with '75\%' in the original string).

Comment: I thought you were onto something there...still not working though...And yes, the deedholder name is exactly correct.  I have copied and pasted it directly from the database that the web data is coming from.  I can query it from the website manually, but I am wanting to get it in the url to save the user from having to do it.

Comment: So I think since there are only 10 parcels out of all 20K that have that, they are going to change the 75% to 3/4.  I hate to admit defeat, but I do not see another way.  Thanks for your help.  This is an interesting problem.

Comment: If you can query from the website manually, you should use your browsers network inspector to check exactly what URL the successful request used.